# Embed Button on image using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to embed button on image using dom. There will be multiple images having multiple button on it which deletes image on click.

I want something like this - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4hozuf/)

Code I tried:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var parent = document.getElementById('images1');
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = 'button';
btn.className="multiple",
div.style.cssText = "position: relative; margin-bottom: 10px ; width: 100%;";
btn.style.cssText = " position: absolute; top: 10px; background-image: url(http://totravelistolearn.in/wp-content/themes/travel/images/cross-512.png); width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 0; background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;";
//textbox.placeholder = 'Add details about attached Image';     
//btn.value = "Remove";                         
btn.onclick = removeImage;
img = new Image();
img.style.display = 'block';
img.className = 'hi1';
img.style.cssText = 'height: 100px; width: 100px; position: relative;';
img.src = results[i];                       
div.appendChild(div);   
div.appendChild(img);                           
div.appendChild(btn);
```

Function to remove image -

```
function removeImage(){
    $$(this).prev("img").remove();  
    $$(this).remove();  
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

Comment: So many duplicate `id`s?

Comment: Actually there will be multiple images which I am selecting from mobile gallery. On image select button will be embedded on each image, which further deletes it on click. So yes there will multiple duplicate `id`'s

Comment: i will suggest you a option to add image in HTMl instead of javascript
you might be rendering images using loop in same time use image HTML code and apply some styling
i can tell you the code if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `class` instead of `id`, also `closest()` will do the job for you: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4hozuf/3/)**

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.MyImage').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for button. But I am not able to work with css. Button not getting placed properly.

Comment: where do you want it to be placed?

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you can remove the div that contains that image and button, like this :

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.MyImage').remove(); 
});
```

As, I wouldn't advice using same `id` on multiple elements in one page, I have changed them to classes and then worked through that. I'd suggest you do the same, if your use-case allows you to.

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j4hozuf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

As I Understand , written this code please check once.

```
function createItem() {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "parent");
    image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg";
    image.style.width = "100%";
    btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("class", "MyButton");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("X");
    btn.appendChild(textnode);
    btn.style.position = "absolute";
    btn.style.left = "10px";
    btn.style.left = "10px";
    div.appendChild(image);
    div.appendChild(btn);
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.overflow = "hidden";
    div.style.marginBottom = "10px";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
createItem();
createItem();
createItem();
parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
console.log(parentDiv.length);
buttonObject = document.getElementsByClassName("MyButton");
for (var i = 0; i < buttonObject.length; i++) {
    buttonObject[i].id = i;
    buttonObject[i].onclick = function() {
        myId = this.getAttribute("id");
        parentDiv[myId].remove()
    }
}
```